# Download and playback video at the same time c# win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am creating a c# winform application that download huge video files and playback them at the same time then ask user 'Do you want to Save the video?'

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\c.mp4", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
        totalBytesRead = 0;
        double divide;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = webStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            if (bytesRead != 0)
            {
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
                writer.Flush();
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            }

        } while (bytesRead != 0);
```

and

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\\c.mp4";
```

With a high download speed there is no problem.
But if download speed be less than play speed problem will begin:
The media player will reach the **Fake end of file** and will stop and playing time will be zero and player will show a black screen.
The only way that i consider is to Pause the player just before stop (Do you know a better way?), but i can't access last frame time.
i tried this with no success:

```
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange += axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange;
void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (e.newState == 8)//Meida ended
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
            HandleUnWantedStop();
            My_Goal_Position= axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a buffer?

Comment: No. How to do this? Thanks.